# A good price to offer - Chinese Numerical Significance

Tags: traditional-characters, number, nuance

I am trying to buy from an older Chinese couple and am trying to come up with an enticing offer. The listing price is 388K but I am looking to pay around 350K.

Someone pointed out that 388 is a good or lucky number so I am looking for a number near 350K that is good and why it is a good number.

Comment: Just tell them 350 is your lucky number and 388 means evil to you.

Comment: Closed as opinion-based. Though it's quite an interesting question.

Comment: @deutschZuid Fair Point. Do you have an opinion?

Comment: @NickMaroulis Yes. All superstitution to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about money and no meaning of language itself.

Answer (score 2):

Anything with 8 or double 8 is best. 68 is or 28 may also be considered favourably. Avoid the use of anything with a 4 as this is associated with the same phonetic sound as death...

I think that covers them all.

Comment: 6 is a good number too.

Answer (score 1):

388 is considered lucky because 3 rhymes with 生 ("live" or "lively") and 8 rhymes with 發 ("rich", "wealthy"). The whole phrase should be [生生發發](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%94%9F%E7%94%9F%E7%99%BC%E7%99%BC&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), but of course, that couple would be going too far if the price was 3388K instead of 388K.

If the price was 150(K), the nearest lucky numbers are 138 "一生(都)發(達)" ("rich throughout your life") and 168 "一路發" ("wealthy all along"). But for 350, I think 388 is already the nearest lucky number. [*Edit:* 338 is actually nearer to 350 than 388 is, but I wonder if the couple is willing to cut the price.]

By the way, the numeral 4 rhymes with 死 ("death"). Some buildings in China don't have a fourth floor (i.e. 4/F is re-numbered as 5/F). 14/F, 24/F, 34/F, 4x/F etc. may be skipped too.